# Ruby on Rails: How do I remove the yarn I created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created the yarn using this:

```
yarn add jquery@3.4.1 bootstrap@3.4.1
```

and it produced a package.json and node modules

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4"
  }
}
```

**yarn.lock**

```
# THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
# yarn lockfile v1


bootstrap@3.4.1:
  version "3.4.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-3.4.1.tgz#c3a347d419e289ad11f4033e3c4132b87c081d72"
  integrity sha512-yN5oZVmRCwe5aKwzRj6736nSmKDX7pLYwsXiCj/EYmo16hODaBiT4En5btW/jhBF/seV+XMx3aYwukYC3A49DA==

jquery@^3.6.4:
  version "3.6.4"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/jquery/-/jquery-3.6.4.tgz#ba065c188142100be4833699852bf7c24dc0252f"
  integrity sha512-v28EW9DWDFpzcD9O5iyJXg3R3+q+mET5JhnjJzQUZMHOv67bpSIHq81GEYpPNZHG+XXHsfSme3nxp/hndKEcsQ==
```

**Gem file:**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.2.0"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.4", ">= 7.0.4.2"

#bootstrap
gem "bootstrap", "~> 5.2.0"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem "pg", "~> 1.1"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

Comment: What do you even mean by Yard? Do you want to remove a dependency or what is it that you're actually asking?

Comment: @max I wanted to remove the files when I added the `yarn bootstrap jquery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yarn remove [package to delete`]

If you want to delete all files, packages and node modules just delete them from your directory.

Comment: I can just remove them directly by deleting them? I can do it without doing the `yarn remove`?

Comment: as I said,  if you only want to remove ONE library --> `yarn remove bootstrap`;
if you want to delete ALL libraries, package.json, yarn.lock and node_modules, delete all this files or `yarn remove bootstrap; yarn remove jquery`; and delete yarn.lock